# Controlando vídeos importados do Vimeo

Tags: jquery, html, vídeo, vimeo-api

Tenho um vídeo importado do Vimeo no meu site através do iframe que o próprio Vimeo gera.

Eu preciso ter um controle sobre ele, como por exemplo, executar uma ação depois que o vídeo terminar.

Existe como?
Alguma sugestão para realizar isso?

Comment: Você já viu esse link http://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api? Dá uma sacada, acho que pode te ajudar.

Comment: @ewertonorg obrigado, vou dar uma olhada.

Comment: Consegui mexendo apenas com `jQuery` usando o código que nosso colega **Ewertonorg** passou. O site que contém as informações é:
https://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api Muito obrigado.